# Python Popen stdin PIPE gets spamed

Tags: python, stdin, popen

I have two simple programs:

test.sh

```
rm ~/out.txt
for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
  read j
  echo "read: '$j'" >> ~/out.txt
done
```

And test.py

```
import sub
process
proc = subprocess.Popen('/Users/plg/test.sh', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write('1\n')
proc.stdin.write('2\n')
```

When I run test.py (using Python 2.7.2), ~/out.txt contains this:

```
read: '1'
read: '2'
read: ''
read: ''
read: ''
...
```

Why does test.sh receive the last 8 lines? It should get stuck and wait for input.
But apparently, Popen spams '\n' once I wrote something and Python exits.

I can't find a fix for this, using proc.stdin.flush() and proc.stdin.close() doesn't do any good. How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Popen is not spamming any output, when your Python program exits test.sh will receive an EOF (end-of-file) indicating that there is nothing left to read, at which point the `read` command in test.sh will give an empty string on each call and give an exit status code of 1.

It doesn't really make sense to have test.sh block on input that will never happen, you would be better off checkin the status code of `read` and exiting if you encounter an EOF or other read error:

```
rm ~/out.txt
for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
  read j
  if [ $? != 0 ]; then
    break
  fi
  echo "read: '$j'" >> ~/out.txt
done
```

Comment: Oh, now I understand! It's like reading from an empty file. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit with the new code, but I'm in a situation where I'm interacting with an external program (java app), and I can't just go modify the source to work like I need it to be, I have to adapt.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
proc = subprocess.Popen('/Users/plg/test.sh', stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
proc.stdin.write('1\n')
proc.stdin.write('2\n')
proc.wait()
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this (in the example, read would need a timeout or Python would wait forever).